# How to update magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 in cloud

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.1, magento2-cloud

Magento just released new versions of Magento Commerce and Open Source to increase product security, performance, and functionality.
One of it is the Magento Commerce and Open Source 2.3.1.

My question is, how to update Magento 2.3.0 to the latest version 2.3.1 in cloud using command line?

Answer (score 0):

In your composer.json file change version to two place

```
"version": "2.3.1"

"magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": "2.3.1"
```

Run below command in local environment

```
composer update
```

Deploy below two files to your cloud it will upgrade to latest version 2.3.1

```
composer.json  
composer.lock
```

Comment: update composer or composer update ?

Comment: Yes composer update, it's my mistake

Comment: I have posted my errors

Comment: you can upgrade magento using same, you do not need to push any file skip this step

Comment: without update how can I push, I need first update my magento

Comment: first you need to change version in your composer.json file on your server then you need to run composer update command.

Comment: Hi @prashant I have added I am getting error while update magento